# Mysql gem troubles with Snow Leopard upgrade

Tags: mysql, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

I have done everything that is on the web (i think)

i have the new 64 bit xcode that came with snow leopard installed

completely removed mysql, removed gems compeltely, removed rails
installed mysql 64 bit, installed gems, installed mysql gem with the env ARCHFLAGS set

I still get this nasty

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes
    from /Users/Navara/Sites/tuosystems/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Navara/Sites/tuosystems/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `rake_original_const_missing'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2503:in `const_missing'
```

Im not sure how to debug this..

any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that i did not reinstall was the problem! RUBY! and doing that fixed it!